# Why Golang allows circular reference in global scope but not in function scope

Tags: go, circular-reference

As I'm writing DB migrations using [gormigrate](https://github.com/go-gormigrate/gormigrate), I need to define a many-to-many relationship between two structs in a function scope. But in golang 1.19 or 1.18 the following won't compile

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type Student struct {
        Courses []*Course
        // [Error] ./prog.go:7:14: undefined: Course
    }
    type Course struct {
        Students []*Student
    }
    fmt.Printf("This won't compile")
}
```

However moving the definitions outside of the function will just work

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Student struct {
    Courses []*Course
}
type Course struct {
    Students []*Student
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("This works")
}
```

Can try this yourself at https://go.dev/play/p/GI53hhlUTbk

Why is this the case? And how can I make it work in a function scope?

Is there a similar syntax to typedef in C++, so we can declare a struct first and then define it later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Circular type references are possible in the package [block](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blocks), but not inside a function.  The section on [Declarations and Scopes](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) in the specification says:

> 2. The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the package block.
>
> ⋮
>
> 8. The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function begins at the identifier in the TypeSpec and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.

Circular references work at package-level because types declared at package-level are scoped to the entire package block.

The scope of a type declared in a function begins at the declaration, not at the beginning of the containing block. A type cannot reference types declared later in the function because those types are not in scope.
It follows that circular type references are not allowed for types declared in a function.

There is not a way to declare the name of a type and later define the type.

Comment: To be absolutely honest - it still does not explain why in one case it allows circular references and in the other - not. OP is okay for the types to be function scoped.

Comment: "Circular references work at package-level because types declared at package-level are scoped to the entire package block." --- it's impossible to agree with it. Why cannot we say "circular references work at function level because types defined at function level are scoped to the entire function body"?

Comment: Okay, it's my fault, I see why now: "The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function **begins** at the identifier" --- highlighted word explains it all, sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: Thanks Cerise. That answered the question. Just diving deeper, why can't the scope of a type begin at the "function block"? I know there's no such thing called "function block", and implicit blocks are only created by "if", "for", and "switch" statements. Why can't it create an implicit block for functions? I guess that was just an unintentional choice when the language was designed?

Comment: Types are scoped the same as variables and constants. The consistency is intentional.